# Google App Engine:Api Page not found after deployment

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Using Golang, I wrote this basic server:

```go
func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/api", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "hello world"})
    })

    router.LoadHTMLGlob("www/*.html")
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    })

    fmt.Println("listening on localhost:8080")

    router.Run("localhost:8080")

}
```

It works fine running on localhost.

After I deploy with `sudo gcloud app deploy`, I browse to the hosting url route for the main page and with static files works fine, but when I browse to `/api` route it throws `Page not found` error (which works locally)

Here is the `app.yaml` used for deploying to App Engine:

```yaml
runtime: go116

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

What I have tried:

- [Enabling Cloud Build API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project)
- [Enabling App Engine Admin API](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841)
- [Using migrate traffic feature from Cloud Console in App Engine to set the default version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/migrating-traffic#migrating_traffic_to_a_new_version)

What am I doing wrong here?

*Note: The Go version I run on localhost is 1.17 but [App Engine supports up to version 1.15](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/runtime#go_versions)*

Comment: Is that your complete YAML file? According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20use%20static%20handlers%2C%20at%20least%20one%20of%20your%20handlers%20must%20contain%20the%20line%20script%3A%20auto%20or%20define%20an%20entrypoint%20element%20to%20deploy%20successfully.), that YAML should not deploy properly. Also, why are you using only static handlers? If you're only serving static files, you should just use Cloud Storage.

Comment: i can serve static resources successfully , problem is with the api

Comment: If my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70175133/13171940) helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the test I made, I would suggest to use the `scripts` handler element in your `app.yaml` as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_element), like this:

```yaml
runtime: go115

handlers:
- url: /(.*)
  script: auto
```

This way, your Go router will serve all your traffic, as stated by the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#:%7E:text=The%20only%20accepted%20value%20for%20the%20script%20element%20is%20auto%20because%20all%20traffic%20is%20served%20using%20the%20entrypoint%20command.):

> The only accepted value for the script element is auto because all traffic is served using the entrypoint command.

Also, I would suggest to change your last line in your code to:

```golang
router.Run()
```

As pointed in this [issue](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/405#issue-101267688) on GitHub:

> ...
> no parameter: `router.Run()`
> Under this API, gin will try to read the `PORT` environment variable and use it.
> If the `PORT` variable is not defined, ":8080" would be used by default.

This advice came after checking the logs on the test deploy I made:

> App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080

For further debugging in your app, I would recommend checking the [Viewing logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for replying !! i will test in few hours

Comment: Did you have opportunity to test the change in the `app.yaml`?

Comment: sorry i was busy in an upwork project i will test tomorrow